# How to run Mojolicious on OpenShift?

Tags: perl, openshift, mojolicious

I already tried https://github.com/degtyarev-dm/mojolicious-lite-openshift but no luck 
it returns 500 error page.

Does anyone know how to run Mojolicious on OpenShift ?

I also tried PerlDancer example, and it run well. But it run on Plack (with PSGI, I don't really understand about PSGI).

Can I use **morbo** / **myapp.pl daemon** / **plackup** command from shell script to start as worker on OpenShift ?

Comment: Mojolicious apps can run under plack, though you cannot use the real-time features like websockets and non-blocking architectures.

Comment: Sir, can you check your twitter... I've sent bug report about daemon/morbo consuming cpu resource when idle

Comment: not only do I not see anything on my twitter, that would not be the appropriate place for a bug report. Additionally that is not the topic of the current question. :sigh:

Comment: hmm, must be different person.. sorry ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I know how to run Mojolicious on OpenShift:

https://github.com/dns/OpenShift-DIY-Perl

Unfortunately unlike heroku, OpenShift block every port except 80 & 443.

The cool things about Openshift, they give 1GB database (shared with app). And mojolicious app can handle file upload. (for comparison: Heroku only give 6MB database & can't handle file upload)

Currently OpenShift using Apache 2.2 with mod_perl.